Translating algebraic ampleness properties to analytic
The following exercise is taken from Hartshorne's book on algebraic geometry:

7.5. Establish the following properties of ample and very ample invertible sheaves on a noetherian scheme $X . \mathscr{L}, \mathscr{M}$ will denote invertible sheaves, and for 4, 5 we assume furthermore that $X$ is of finite type over a noetherian ring $A$.

If $\mathscr{L}$ is ample and $\mathscr{M}$ is generated by global sections, then $\mathscr{L} \otimes \mathscr{M}$ is ample.
If $\mathscr{L}$ is ample and $\mathscr{M}$ is arbitrary, then $\mathscr{M} \otimes \mathscr{L}^{n}$ is ample for sufficiently large $n$.
If $\mathscr{L}, \mathscr{M}$ are both ample, so is $\mathscr{L} \otimes \mathscr{M}$.
If $\mathscr{L}$ is very ample and $\mathscr{M}$ is generated by global sections, then $\mathscr{L} \otimes \mathscr{M}$ is very ample.
If $\mathscr{L}$ is ample, then there is an $n_{0}>0$ such that $\mathscr{L}^{n}$ is very ample for all $n \geqslant n_{0}$.


In the analytic setting we say that a line bundle $L$ over a complex manifold $M$ is very ample if $H^0(M,L)$ separates points and directions. $H^0(M,L)$ is said to separate points if for every pair of distinct points $p, q \in M$, there exists a global holomorphic section $\sigma$ of $L$ such that $() = 0$ and $() ≠ 0$. $H^0(M,L)$ separates directions if for every $p \in M$ and every nonzero $v \in T'_pM$, there is a global holomorphic section $\sigma$ such that $() = 0$ and $v\hat{\sigma}(p) \ne 0$, where $\hat{\sigma}$ is the component function of $$ with respect to some holomorphic local frame.
Given these definitions, can one translate these algebraic properties to the analytic setting or do we run into some issues trying to do so?

Is there a problem with applying the algebraic proofs verbatim in the analytic setting?
